# docker mysql volumes compose connect error

Tags: mysql, docker

When using this docker-compose.yml volumes parameter:

```
volumes:
- data:/var/lib/mysql
```

php access to mysql database works normally

but when I attempt this (in order to store mysql data to host machine):

```
volumes:
- /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I get the `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002`) error

Why is this error occurring and how can I store mysql data to host machine without this error?

Answer (score 1):

That particular error doesn't tell you much other you can't connect to your DB.

If your volume configuration is all you changed, then most likely, what is happening is that the user running your database process in Docker does not have permission to access or modify the corresponding directory on the host.

Here is a link to an article that goes in depth on the subject: https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca

**tl;dr** Make sure the user that is running your DB process in your container is part of a group with a GID that matches the GID of a group on the host that has read and write permissions over that directory. The article has precise instructions at the end.